# MySQL extract results by delimeter

Tags: mysql, search, delimiter

I have a quick (hopefully simple) question.  I have some information stored in a MySQL database:

```
|info1=value1
|info2=value2
|info3=value3
|info4=value4
|info5=value5
|info6=value6
```

I need to be able to get a certain set of information form this.  Let's pretend that this set of data is in each record in a table called options.  I need to be able to extract `info3` value information, meaning that I need to (for every record) recieved the "`value3`" section of the record.  I don't need "`|info3=`", just the "`value3`"; the actual value of "`value3`" is different for each record.

Comment: Oh good Lord. Do you actually *need* to emulate a database inside a database? I'd suggest to parse the string into a [temporary] table (split by `|`, the part before `=` is the column name) and then work with that table through normal MySQL.

Comment: The data is already there - what I'm trying to do is use PHP to just grab a certain value and let PHP generate a list of all the records with this.  The core application is an extension for MediaWiki, and I'm just trying to extract information from a generated infobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is simple, alright.

I don't think the same can be told about the answer:

```
select substring_index(
    substring_index(
       old_text
       ,'info3=',-1),'|',1)
from mw_text;
```

This should do what you want.

BUT, I really hope that this is just for play, otherwise, I would recomend that you review your database design.

Comment: What about your substring text - the values are always different; how do I search based on not knowing the values (the info# will always be the same) - just not the value#'s.

Comment: the value is what is returned by the select above. You set the "'info3='" part and get the value for that info.

Comment: This technically works, however, I'd want to retrieve the information per query, so for instance there are 100 records that a select statement would need to go through, for instance `select old_text from mw_text;`.  So, that would get me each record, and then I'd like to run your above, and have it dynamically  search for the correct information, and only display that in the end.  Not sure if this makes sense or not.

Comment: I'm assuming on my edit that old_text is the name of your `field` and `mw_text` the name of you table...